# Filename is not changing while sharing pdf files in Android

Tags: android, react-native

I am using react-native-share library to share a pdf file.  I am sharing by converting it to base64 string but I am unable to change filename.

```
  shareProfile = async(data) => {
    Share.open({url: `data:application/pdf;base64, ${data}`, filename: 'test'})
  }
```

I found property in documents but still it is not working. It is frustrating. 
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I'm running into this same issue. There appears to be a fix for this which was merged into their master branch, a few short weeks ago. However when react-native-share is installed via npm / yarn for some reason it doesn't include the fix.

Here's the fix commit:
https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-share/pull/689/commits

And if you look at the source code -- you can see that it has been successfully merged.

I tried copying/pasting his fix into my local repo and it works (file names on android share worked), unfortunately we need to be able to get the fix from the source code.